# Extra height added to page, can't find what's causing it

Tags: html

My page has extra space coming from somewhere and I can't figure out where it's coming from.

http://demamusic.com/contact/

Comment: You didn't even put any effort into this question. How are we supposed to know where to look for the space you're talking about?

Comment: What? What space? Where?

Comment: Look into inspect elements. https://www.google.com/search?q=inspect+element+safari+chrome&oq=inspect+element+safari+chrome&aqs=chrome..69i57.6700j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&safe=active&q=inspect+element+safari+and+chrome

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the following in style.css:

```
footer {
    margin-top: 42%;
}
```

That's your culprit. Please be more explicit in asking your question next time.

Comment: Thanks for the help and feedback. Thought I had a media query applying that margin to mobile devices only. I also thought the question would be self explanatory as the space is pretty obvious once you visit the link.

Comment: I only understood it when I looked at the title again. It's better you give all relevant info in the body too. That way your question doesn't attract downvotes. You can flag this as the accepted answer so others don't bother opening it, if your problem has been solved.

Comment: Just want to drop a hint here: If you use chrome, it's quite easy to find the source of your css headaches, by right-clicking and inspecting the part of the page you're having problems with. On the right hand of the dev tools, you will see the styles that apply to the element. Just in case you didn't know this